# Why can't admin access private file?

Tags: 8, files

I have a file field as part of a Paragraph. The Paragraph is attached to a node bundle. Each paragraph can hold a single file.

I have added the same file to the node (each in its own paragraph) multiple times. When I edit the node I see all 5 paragraphs and links to all 5 of the files (myfile.pdf, myfile_0.pdf, myfile_1.pdf, etc). When I look in file_managed table all the files have a record and they all look correct (status = 1, other details seem correct). All 5 of the files are on the server and have R world privileges.

As admin, 4 of the files open correctly. 1 of them gives Access Denied.

Any suggestion as to what I could be missing?

Comment: Is it the same paragraph or maybe there's a difference in Paragraph settings? Are the path to the files generally the same?

Comment: Same paragraph type (document) and these are multiple instances of that paragraph on the same node. The paths are identical (sorry, didnt include path above).

Comment: I can't think of much to test other than to check which file ID (media ID?) the paragraph instances are referencing, then check those IDs in the database.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, these are the same files, but renamed 5 times? I'm assuming since you posted the server permissions, you've seen all 5 files on server? Have you tried to download the 5 files off of the server (not thru Drupal UI) and open them all? I assume you have uploaded a different file to test and it also failed. I know this is basic - but it's a start.